# Updating data on a table with Ajax Prototype

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, prototypejs

im using PrototypeJS for my project, i used Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater, inserts in realtime as i wanted, but it doesn't replace the data inside my table here is the html code

```
<table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th id="products"></th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the code for the js

```
new Ajax.PeriodicalUpdater('products', 'test.php',
  {
    method: 'get',
    insertion: Insertion.Top,
    frequency: 1,
    decay: 1
  }
);
```

But the result it's bad, it adds and adds everytime the same data, it doesn't replace, what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're inserting, so it... inserts.

FYI, [Insertion.Top is deprecated](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/insertion) in favor of [Element#insert](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/insert), but what you'd want is [Element#replace](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/replace).

However, the *default* is to replace--by specifying an `insertion` property you're overriding the default. See the [Updater docs](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/updater) for more details.

Comment: So i remove the "Insertion" parameter? or i have to replace Insertion.Top to Element#replace?